# Rolling sum with double indexing in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyverse, rolling-computation

I would like to calculate a rolling sum or a rolling count with respect to two index columns in R. The following data table has a column that shows the amount of sale and two date columns. I would like to create a 4th column that gives me the number of dates in Column index2 that are smaller than the date in Column index1, and I also want to have 5th column that gives me the sum of sales associated with those counted in the fourth column.

```
sales_vec <- c(2, 4, 3, 5)
index1_vec <- as.Date("2019-08-29") + c(0, 2, 5, 6)
index2_vec <- as.Date("2019-08-29") + c(-5, 2, 1, -3)
company <- tibble(
  sales = sales_vec,
  index1 = index1_vec ,
  index2 = index2_vec 
)

> print(company)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  sales index1     index2    
  <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     2 2019-08-29 2019-08-24
2     4 2019-08-31 2019-08-31
3     3 2019-09-03 2019-08-30
4     5 2019-09-04 2019-08-26
```

My outcome should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  sales index1     index2     rollingCount rollingSum
  <dbl> <date>     <date>            <dbl>      <dbl>
1     2 2019-08-29 2019-08-24            2          7
2     4 2019-08-31 2019-08-31            3         10
3     3 2019-09-03 2019-08-30            4         14
4     5 2019-09-04 2019-08-26            4         14
```

The first row of rollingCount is 2 because there are two dates in Column index2 that are smaller than the first row of index1, and the sum of sales associated with those two rows are 2 + 5 =7, which shows up in the first row of rollingSum. The second row of rollingCount is 3 because there are three dates in Column index2 that are smaller than the second row of index1, and the sum of sales associated with those three rows are 2 + 5 + 3 = 10, which shows up in the second row of rollingSum. And so on.

I am familiar with the family of "slide" commands to do rolling calculations but I am struggling with this task as it has two index columns.

Comment: Do you need `sapply(company$index1, function(x) {i1 <- company$index2  < x; sum(company$sales[i1]) })`

Comment: @chinsoon12 Yes, a tidyverse solution would be my preference. However, if there are other solutions, they would also be helpful as they could suggest useful thought processes that may open a tidyverse door!

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for noticing that typo. I am going to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `sapply` to loop over the 'index1' column, create an logical vector with `index2` column, use that to get the `sum` of logical vector and the `sum` of subset of 'sales'

```
cbind(company, t(sapply(company$index1, function(x) {
        i1 <- company$index2  < x
    c(rollingCount = sum(i1), rollingSum = sum(company$sales[i1])) })))
#  sales     index1     index2 rollingCount rollingSum
#1     2 2019-08-29 2019-08-24            2          7
#2     4 2019-08-30 2019-08-31            3         10
#3     3 2019-09-03 2019-08-30            4         14
#4     5 2019-09-04 2019-08-26            4         14
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(company$index1, ~ {
       i1 <- company$index2 < .x
       tibble(rollingCount = sum(i1), rollingSum = sum(company$sales[i1]))}) %>%
    bind_cols(company, .)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  sales index1     index2     rollingCount rollingSum
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>            <int>      <dbl>
#1     2 2019-08-29 2019-08-24            2          7
#2     4 2019-08-30 2019-08-31            3         10
#3     3 2019-09-03 2019-08-30            4         14
#4     5 2019-09-04 2019-08-26            4         14
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Based on your solution, it is what I have developed which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

```company <- company %>%
  mutate(
    rollingCount = slide_dbl   (.x = index1,         ~{sum(index2 < .x)}),
    rollingSales = slide_dbl    (.x = index1,         ~{sum(sales[index2 < .x])}),
   )```

Answer (score 2):

Here are couple of approaches :

Using `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

company %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(rollingCount = sum(index1 > .$index2), 
         rollingSum = sum(.$sales[index1 > .$index2]))


#  sales index1     index2     rollingCount rollingSum
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>            <int>      <dbl>
#1     2 2019-08-29 2019-08-24            2          7
#2     4 2019-08-31 2019-08-31            3         10
#3     3 2019-09-03 2019-08-30            4         14
#4     5 2019-09-04 2019-08-26            4         14
```

and using `map_dbl` from `purrr` :

```
company %>%
   mutate(rollingCount = map_dbl(index1, ~{
                 vec <- .x > index2
                 sum(vec)
                 }),
          rollingSum = map_dbl(index1, ~sum(sales[.x > index2])))
```

Comment: Thanks! In your second approach, is it possible to break the operations inside ```~sum(sales[.x > index2])```? I mean, define a function that first calculates ```vec <- (.x > index2)``` and then calculates ```sum(vec)```. The reason is that I would like to do more elaborated calculations on ```vec```.